# Fetch email using message id with php imap?

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am developing a small webmail application, what i need to do is thread the emails like what Gmail does .

I planned on achieving it by getting '`references`' of a mail (using `uid`) and then showing them as one thread. I get the references like this:

```
    $inbox = imap_open("{imap.example.org:143}INBOX", "username", "password");
    $email_number = imap_msgno($inbox,$uid);
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $mess = $overview[0];
    $refs = array_filter(explode(' ', htmlentities($mess->references)));
```

The `$refs` array is an array of `Message-Id's` , can anyone tell me how to fetch a mail based on a `Message-Id`  .

If i can get a `Message UID` or `Message Sequence Number` from a `Message-Id` that also would suffice.

An alternative that came up in my mind was to achieve this is by using `imap_search()` for searching mails with same subject(after stripping 'Re:' from it etc) but i don't think it would be ideal.

Can anyone give me helpful pointers as to how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Some IMAP servers will allow you to search by Message-ID (`SEARCH HEADER Message-ID string`), but a lot of server software seems to implement this poorly.

In general, there is no way to fetch a message by its Message-ID header.  Most clients download the headers (including the Message-ID) of all messages, store them, and then post-process them, matching them up with other messagesbased on `References` and `In-Reply-To` headers.  However: If you're using Gmail, you can use its [extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions) to grab Gmail's internal thread-id, which they call `X-GM-THRID`.

Comment: Thanks Max ,but is there a way to search header with php , like with imap_search or any other function where i can do `SEARCH HEADER Message-ID string`?

Comment: Sorry, I know IMAP, not PHP, so I'm giving general information that should be translatable into any given library, if it's extensible enough.  imap_search is where I'd start, yes.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$result = imap_search($imapResource, "TEXT \"<mymessageid@host.com>\"", SE_UID);
if(is_array($result) && count($result) == 1){
    echo $result[0];
}
```